# Наследование. Виртуальный функции

Tags: c++, функции, перегрузка-операторов

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: в производном классе есть метод, а в `main()` надо создать массив указателей на базовый, и чтобы они ссылались на производный, затем надо из указателей базового вызвать метод производного.

```
class A{};
class B :public A
{
    B operator+(B& obj)
    {}
};

    int main()
    {
        A** ptrA = new A*[3];
        B obj[3];
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            ptrA[i] = &obj[i];

        *(ptrA + 0) = *(ptrA + 1) + *(ptrA + 2); //не работает
        return 0;   
    }
```

Comment: Срочно читать учебник по C++. Чтобы полиморфизм работал нужны виртуальные функции и их объявления в _базовом_ классе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Статический тип, например, следующего выражения

```
*(ptrA + 0)
```

есть `class A *`. То есть это указатель.

В самом же классе не определен оператор `operator +` . Поэтому компилятор в любом случае выдаст сообщение об ошибке.

К тому же в классе `B` аналогичный оператор определен, как имеющий `private` метод доступа, да к тому же ничего не возвращает и не может иметь дело с временными объектами.

Кроме того сам оператор присваивания должен быть объявлен как виртуальный

И в предложении

```
*(ptrA + 0) = *(ptrA + 1) + *(ptrA + 2);
```

Складываются и присваиваются указатели, так как тип, например, выражения `*(ptrA + 2)` есть `A *`

Программа может выглядеть следующим образом

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    virtual ~A() {}
    virtual A & operator =( const A & )
    {
        std::cout << "A::operator =( const A & )" << std::endl;
        return *this;
    }
    virtual A & operator +( const A & )
    {
        std::cout << "A::operator +( const A & )" << std::endl;
        return *this;
    }       
};

class B :public A
{
    B & operator =( const A & ) override
    {
        std::cout << "B::operator =( const A & )" << std::endl;
        return *this;
    }
    B & operator +( const A & ) override
    {
        std::cout << "B::operator +( const A & )" << std::endl;
        return *this;
    }       
};

int main()
{
    const int N = 3;

    A** ptrA = new A * [N];
    B obj[N];

    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ ) ptrA[i] = &obj[i];

    **(ptrA + 0) = **(ptrA + 1) + **(ptrA + 2);

    delete [] ptrA;

    return 0;
}
```

Ее вывод на консоль:

```
B::operator +( const A & )
B::operator =( const A & )
```

Answer (score 0):

1. В коде несколько косяков. http://codepad.org/yUgF8NAD - попытка их исправить.
2. Это всё равно не заработает, т. к. оператора сложения у класса `A` нет.
   Можно исправить так, но это немного не то: http://codepad.org/B6wLRno9

   ```
   class A
   {
       public: virtual A & operator + (const A &obj) = 0;
   };

   class B : public A
   {
       public: B & operator + (const A &obj)
       {
           return *this;
       }
   };

   int main()
   {
       A** ptrA = new A*[3];
       B obj[3];
       for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
           ptrA[i] = &obj[i];

       *ptrA[0] = *ptrA[1] + *ptrA[2];
       return 0;   
   }
   ```